# Disable ScollViewer scrolling programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7

Image is larger than scrollviewer area, when scrolling to a certain point, I need to click a button and stop the scrollviewer from scrolling, and after finishing drawing on the image, then start scroll again.
Is there a solution or good structure for this, or I might use the wrong control to achieve this? Thanks

```
 
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ImageScroll">
    <Image x:Name="ImageDraw" MouseLeftButtonDown="ImageDraw_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="ImageDraw_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonUp="ImageDraw_MouseLeftButtonUp" >
    </Image>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the scrollviewer by changing the XxxxalScrollBarVisibility properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility(v=VS.95).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.horizontalscrollbarvisibility(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled",VerticalScrollBarVisibility ="Disabled": It stops scrolling, but it shows the full image on the screen, not the part of the image I am scrolling to. Still cannot draw on the area of the image.